# Semaphore is deadlocking by halting code running on own thread

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

In order to be able to run a library which doesn't scale really well in multithreaded environments I have created an object pool to automatically create a limited number of instances so to increase the total throughput. I am using a `SemaphoreSlim` to lock/unlock access to the underlying instances.

For completeness, the `ObjectPool<T>` derived from is found [here on MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/collections/thread-safe/how-to-create-an-object-pool).

```
/// <summary>
/// An object pool with a fixed amount of objects.
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="T">The type to have in this pool</typeparam>
public class FixedObjectPool<T> : ObjectPool<T>
    where T : class
{
    private int _maxObjectCount;
    private SemaphoreSlim _objectAvailable;

    public FixedObjectPool(Func<T> objectGenerator, int maxObjectCount) : base(objectGenerator)
    {
        _maxObjectCount = maxObjectCount;
        _objectAvailable = new SemaphoreSlim(0, maxObjectCount);
    }

    public override T GetObject()
    {
        _objectAvailable.Wait(10);
        return base.GetObject();
    }

    public override void PutObject(T item)
    {
        base.PutObject(item);
        _objectAvailable.Release();
    }
}
```

This class is supposed to be invoked several thousand times each second. Unless a timeout period is specified (currently 10ms), a call to the `GetObject` method seems to deadlock.

My 2 cents are that calling code is running on the same thread which gets locked, therefore the semaphore not being released.

How can I make sure, by design in this class, that method calls are dispatched on their own threads, with the goal of making sure that semaphore waits do not deadlock by halting running code outside this method?

**Edit:** Upon request, usage of the pool currently happens like in the following block;

```
Parallel.For(0, 10000, (i) => {
    var instance = pool.GetObject();
    // Do something with said instance
    pool.PutObject(instance);
});
```

Comment: Can you show us some of the code that uses the pool?

Comment: It looks like your pool is initially empty, so are you adding objects to it before trying to get them back out?

Comment: @Sean See updated question. If no instance is available in the pool a new one is instantiated on the fly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You initialize your semaphore with an initial count of zero:

```
_objectAvailable = new SemaphoreSlim(0, maxObjectCount);
```

This means that all who call `Wait` will block, regardless of what thread they are on.

Comment: That's so small... Yet so significant.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you're setting the initial count of your semaphore to zero:

```
_objectAvailable = new SemaphoreSlim(0, maxObjectCount);
```

This means that when you call `GetObject` there won't be anything available and the semaphore will timeout.

Your pool starts out as empty, so you need to put something into it first. This will increase the semaphore count and will also mean you've got something to get!

You mention that the class doesn't scale well in a multithreaded environment, and I'm not sure your solution will work. You're basically waiting on a semaphore and then creating the object anyway by calling the base class. When you're using the semaphore correctly you will end up with multiple threads able to call into the base class at the same time, which means the base class will have to be thread safe.

Comment: You mean the `ObjectPool<T>`? As there's an `ConcurrentBag<T>` I'm honestly not that worried about concurrency. Should I? In my case the object that's not thread-safe is the generic `T`.